# How to create database collection with typeorm on Atlas MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm, mongodb-atlas

I have been using Mysql and pg Typeorm with Nestjs on projects which work fine. I decided to use mongo Atlas, I have connected successfully to Atlas with no error but collection not created. Whenever I use mysql with these steps, the table will be created.

That is not happening with mongo, maybe I am not doing something right

I also installed dependency

```
npm i --save @nestjs/typeorm typeorm @types/mongodb mongodb
```

ormconfig.json

```
{
    "type": "mongodb",
    "url": "mongodb+srv://dbUser:<password>@<database>.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "useNewUrlParser": true,
    "synchronize": true,
    "useUnifiedTopology": true,
    "logging": true,
    "ssl": true,
    "entities": [
        "dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"
    ]
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot()],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

test.entity.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, CreateDateColumn, ObjectIdColumn, ObjectID } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('Test')
export class TestEntity {
    @ObjectIdColumn()
    id: ObjectID;

    @Column()
    firstName: string;

    @Column()
    lastName: string;

    @Column()
    age: number;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    created: Date;
}
```

I appreciate your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection will be created when you attempt to insert your first document.

Just another tip. I noticed in your entity you are inserting a '@CreateDateColumn()'. MongoDB ObjectId contains a timestamp, which represents the creation date of the document.

[MongoDB ObjectId Details](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)